# How to upload new repo to BitBucket using git with SSH on Linux command line only?

Tags: linux, ssh, git

Steps I've taken:

`ssh-keygen` my key

`ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/<private_key_file>` my key

Add the public key to my BitBucket Account settings

`git config --add --global core.sshComand 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa'` add my SSH key to git config

And still when I try to push my repo git is asking me for username/password.
What did I do wrong? Or do I have to specify a git option to push using SSH key instead of basic auth?

git version is 2.37.1
OS version is Ubuntu LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH keys only work with SSH remotes – they cannot be used if the Git repository is configured to push to an "https://" URL (because that's not SSH).

Use `git remote set-url` to change it to the corresponding SSH address. For BitBucket, it's shown in the repository's "Clone" popup after you select 'SSH' in the corner menu. For example:

- Either:

  ```
  $ git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:User/Project.git
  ```
- Or:

  ```
  $ git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/User/Project.git
  ```